# Ternary Operators and Macros #define

Tags: c, macros, ternary

I am confused on the ternary operator outputs if it is used in a macro. Why is the output 3 and 0?

```
#define test(x,y)(! y ? 0 : x/y)

int main(void){
printf("%d",test(2+2,2));
printf("%d",test(4,-1-1));
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are confused about the usage of a macro, copy-paste it where it is being used and evaluate from there:

```
int main(void){
    printf("%d", ! 2 ? 0 : 2+2 / 2);
    printf("%d", ! -1 - 1 ? 0 : 4 / -1 - 1);
    return(0);
}
```

---

The second argument to the first `printf` call goes: if `! 2` is true, return `0`, otherwise return the expression `(2+2) / 2`. Since `! 2` is false, the expression `2+2 / 2` is returned, and its result is clearly `3`.

---

The second argument to the second `printf` call goes: if `! -1 - 1` is true, return `0`, otherwise return the expression `4 / -1 - 1`.

The expression `! -1 -1` is actually interpreted as `!(-1) - 1`, since the `!` (logical NOT) operator has precedence over the `-` (subtraction) operator.

`!(-1)` becomes `0` (`-1` is a truthy value, which, when negated, becomes a falsy one, i.e. `0`).

Then, `0 - 1` becomes `-1`, which is a truthy value, therefore the truthy value of the ternary operator is returned, i.e. `0`.

---